# Custom formatting SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have this data.

```
city        value 

seoul       2.42999
tokyo       5.70109
```

I would like to format the numbers to 0 decimals if the city is Seoul, and format to show 3 decimals if city is Tokyo.

I tried something like this and it didn't work.

```
=IIF(Fields!CityName.Value="seoul",N0,N3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

format specifiers are strings, add quotes.
also, you may need to trim field value

`=IIF(Trim(Fields!CityName.Value) ="seoul","N0","N3")`